# Set toDate as not mandatory field in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, bootstrap-modal

I have a scenario where user adds `VendorName`, `FromDate` & `ToDate`. With my current code its validating all the three mentioned fields.

But now, I dont want to validate `ToDate` field.

Below is my html for the same

```
<tr id="vendorlisttr1">
  <td>
    <div class="row noPadding vendorForm">
      <div class="vendorDaterow">
        <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData1">
          <label>OnM SP vendor name</label><span><input type="text" value="" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName1" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="vendorFromDate">
          <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate1" readonly="readonly" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="vendorToDate">
          <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spToDate" id="spToDate1" readonly="readonly" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="add">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And here is how I validate them.

```
var vendorError = false;
$(".vendorForm input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        jAlert(ValidationMessageConfig.vendorErrorMessage, ValidationMessageConfig.Title);
        vendorError = true;
        return false;
    }
})
if (vendorError) {
    return false;
}
```

So how should I stop validating `ToDate` ?

**Important: I cannot use hardcode Id**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:not() Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

> Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

Use the below selector

```
$(".vendorForm input:not(#spToDate1)")
```

You can also use [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(".vendorForm input").not('#spToDate1')
```

Comment: i cannot use hardcode `id` because of some other reasons

Comment: What attribute can you access?

Comment: i can access the class which i have mentioned in my html

Comment: Do you mean the class of div ?

Comment: Use this then `$(".vendorForm input").not('input[name=spToDate]')` or `$(".vendorForm input").not($('.vendorToDate').find('input'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$(".vendorForm input").not("#spToDate1")
```

But since you cannot use the `id`, you can consider the selector: `input[name!='spToDate']`

```
  var vendorError = false;
    $(".vendorForm input[name!='spToDate']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            jAlert(ValidationMessageConfig.vendorErrorMessage, ValidationMessageConfig.Title);
            vendorError = true;
            return false;
        }
    })
    if (vendorError) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var vendorError = false;
$(".vendorForm input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).attr("id") != 'spToDate1') {
        jAlert(ValidationMessageConfig.vendorErrorMessage, ValidationMessageConfig.Title);
        vendorError = true;
        return false;
    }
})
if (vendorError) {
    return false;
}
```